# How do you underline text in PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

Where in the tools will you be able to add a stroke under the font? I cant find it in styles. Is there a toolbar to simply,

- underline text?

Comment: I don't mean to be blunt, but LMGTFY. A simple search with exactly the text of your question yields 1.28 **million** results. -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it under the options in **Window → Character**. This answers should be easily googleable and is in the [manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/formatting-characters.html) (it which is generally recommended skim read it at least).

[image]

**Image 1**: Underline